# how change radio button with image or text and how using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

I want to make voting only + and - using the radio buttons. and I've run it, with the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<label>+<label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<label>-<label>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but the question is how to replace the radio with images or text such as + and -, see several ways in google and I can change the style of a radio button with an image or text but eventually onlick that exist in the radio so it does not work

anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: You can use button or image instead radio. I think that's better. Look this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vq2v6nk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it with images by using `onclick` and passing 1 for the 'plus' and -1 for the 'minus'

```js
function getVote(vote) {
    if(vote == 1){
        alert('you voted up');
    }
    else{
        alert('you voted down');
    }
}
```

```css
img{
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
    <img onclick="getVote(1)" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/plus-.png" />
    <img onclick="getVote(0)" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFArejAZiRfXrGQqRxw0RpelEfLBdSzCdM01pGi6bdvHYz7HEi"  />
</div>
```

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah, no problem. Let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
<input id="0" type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<label for="0">+<label>
<br>
<input id="1" type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<label for="1">-<label>
</form>
```

In the label tag , You can put anything or image or text. 
Only click the content of the label  just like click radio0 or radio1.

Comment: thank you, but i need the circle is hiden and change with images / just text.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to style the label. Link it with the `for` attribute. If you want an image, add an image in the label or use a bg image.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  color: #CCC;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="plus" name="vote" value="0">
<label for="plus">+<label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="neg" name="vote" value="1">
<label for="neg">-<label>
```